# How do I permanently set a different service plugin or provider in neutron via Juju?

Tags: juju, openstack

In default configuration, there is a following line in neutron.conf under neutron-api charm:

`service_plugins = neutron.services.l3_router.l3_router_plugin.L3RouterPlugin,neutron.services.firewall.fwaas_plugin.FirewallPlugin,neutron.services.loadbalancer.plugin.LoadBalancerPlugin....`

but i want to permanently use:

```
service_plugins = neutron.plugins.brocade.vyatta.vrouter_neutron_plugin.VyattaVRouterPlugin.....
```

Same scenario at service providers, when I want to add a new one, e.g.:

```
service_provider = LOADBALANCER:....
```

Where can I set this explicitly?

1. if the charm is already deployed
2. when i deploy the brand new charm

Every time I restart the juju services or reboot the node with the charm, juju overwrite all changes... Drives me crazy...